# Deleting Nested Reviews Deletes the whole Post Created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I am setting a nested review scaffold inside the Post scaffold however, when i try to delete a review that is nested inside the show page in the Post, The whole post is deleted. how can i delete only the reviews without the post?

here's my code:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user! , except: [:index,:show]
  before_filter :check_user, only: [:edit,:update,:destroy]


  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json

  def search
    if params[:search].present?
    @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
    else
    @posts = Post.all
    end
  end

  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @posts = Post.all
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @reviews = Review.where(post_id: @post.id)
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end


  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description,:image,:all_tags)
    end

    def check_user
      if  current_user.id != @post.user_id
      redirect_to root_path , alert: "Sorry this Post belongs to someone else"
    end
    end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
    resources :posts do
      collection do
        get 'search'
  end
      resources :reviews , except: [:show,:index] do
    member do
      get "like" => "reviews#upvote"
      get "dislike" => "reviews#downvote"
    end
  end

end
  get 'pages/help'

  get 'pages/blog'

  get 'pages/contact'
  get 'pages/tour'

  resources :posts
  root 'posts#index'

  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: "tag"
end
```

**reviews_controller.rb**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [ :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote,:downvote]
  before_action :set_post
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  respond_to :html



  def new
    @review = Review.new
    respond_with(@review)
  end

    def edit
    end


  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.post_id = @post.id
    @review.save
    redirect_to post_path(@post)


  end

  def update
    @review.update(review_params)
    respond_with(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_with(@review)
  end

  def upvote
    @review.upvote_from current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @review.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end




  private
    def set_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_post
      unless @post = Post.where(id: params[:post_id]).first
        redirect_to posts_path, flash: {alert: "Post doesn't exists"}
      end
    end

    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:comment)
    end
end
```

**models/review.rb**

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

**models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick
  has_many :reviews , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
  #Paperclip Installation
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]


  def all_tags=(names)
  self.tags = names.split(",").map do |name|
      Tag.where(name: name.strip).first_or_create!
  end
end

def all_tags
  self.tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
end

def self.tagged_with(name)
  Tag.find_by_name!(name).posts
end

end
```

**views/posts/index.html.erb**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>

      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
      <tr>
        <td><h4><%=link_to post.title , post%></h4></td>
        <td><%=raw tag_links(post.all_tags)%></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
        </tr>
    <%end%>
  </tbody>
</table>



<%= link_to 'new post', new_post_path %>
```

**views/posts/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="right-align">
      <h2><%= @post.title %></h2>
      <hr>
    </div>

    <%if @post.image.exists?%>
    <%= image_tag @post.image.url(:medium) %>
    <%end%>

    <div class="right-align">
      <%=  markdown @post.description %>

    <br>

    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tbody>
        <% @reviews.each do |review|%>
        <tr>
        <td >
          Welcome back <%= current_user.name %>
          <h4><%= link_to "like" ,like_post_review_path(@post, review) , class: " btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"%></h4>
          <p><%= review.get_upvotes.size%></p>
          <p><%= review.get_downvotes.size%></p>
          <h4><%= link_to "Dislike" , dislike_post_review_path(@post, review)  , class: "btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"%></h4>
        <p><%=  markdown review.comment %></p>
        <p><%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_review_path(@post, review) %></p>
        <p><%= link_to 'Destroy', @review, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>




        </td>
      </tr>
        <%end%>


      </tbody>
    </table>




    <p><%= link_to 'Write Review', new_post_review_path(@post) , class: "btn btn-primary" %></p>


    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

    </div>

</div>
```

**Update:**

i tried changing the code as suggested in the destroy method and in the Reviews Controller and the Post Show page but still getting the error. Here's the error i am getting :
[image]

Comment: Hey, looks like you changed the wrong code. You changed the `post` delete action instead of the `review` delete action. Re-read my answer from below and make sure you change the line that has @review in it.

Answer (score 0):

Look like a typo, change:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Destroy', @review, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
```

to:

```
<p><%= link_to 'Destroy', review, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
```

and change your reviews controller destroy:

```
def destroy
  @review.destroy
  redirect_to :back
end
```

Comment: i tried changing that before but i get this error: ' NameError in Posts#index'